# Hide div's containing Youtube while printing a webpage

Tags: html, css, printing, print-style

I'm creating a print stylesheet for a webpage which, next to text content, also contains youtube embeds in the content area (for instance).

I don't want to print the youtube's, so I added `display:none` to the print stylesheet for these `div`'s.

Now the `div`'s are not printed but in the print preview they do take empty space, and thus pushing the text content beneath them.

Resulting in a lot of white space with text under this white space. Not nice. Is there a solution or trick to solve this?

Code:

```
<div class="bigblok_image">
<object height="325" width="400"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/waVIqjB0WAU&amp;hl=nl&amp;fs=1"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/waVIqjB0WAU&amp;hl=nl&amp;fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" height="325" width="400">
</object>
```

```
div.bigblok_image { display: none; }
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show?  It sounds like your YouTube DIVs are embedded in other DIVs that are controlling the layout.

Comment: The posted code has no errors, can you post a link to a sample page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following in the head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print"/>
```

In print.css add the following:

```
#div-to-be-hidden
{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's what I'm doing. I see now the div's are inside <p> tags too. But setting the div inside the p to display: none should at least result in less space than they are taking now.